# How to forward ports to play mario kart 8 on nintendo switch on a consumer router (huawei WS5200)?

Tags: wireless-router, nat

I have a HUAWEI WiFi WS5200 router that only supports one-by-one port forwarding setting. I can't specify a range.

The [Nintendo Guide](https://es-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22272/%7E/how-to-set-up-a-routers-port-forwarding-for-a-nintendo-switch-console) says to port-forward 1024 to 65535 which I can't on this router.

Mario Kart 8 online mode fails with error 2618-0516 when finding players.

How can I make it work?

Comment: First question I have are you behind a CGNAT?

Comment: It seems I am. The public address on https://whatsmyip.com/ differs from the router wan ip 100.64.48.185.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being behind a CGNAT means you can't open incoming ports at all. You will need to either have the ISP give you a proper routable IP address (most ISPs will offer that but some charge extra) or use a VPN service that gives you a routable IP address.

After you get a proper IP address you will need to handle the incoming connection issue on your local router. Because it seems that Mario Kart uses completely random ports you will need to use the DMZ option on your router, which basically means that you set a specific internal IP address on your network, which will receive all incoming connections on all ports except those specifically routed to a different internal IP. You can also try using UPnP, which allows devices to dynamically route incoming ports, but I'm not sure whether the Switch supports that.

One last thing - If you can't get a real IP from your ISP and have to resort to using a VPN, I seriously doubt the Switch would support that. You will need to set up a router that tunnels all connections from and to the Switch through the VPN. A Raspberry Pi is perfect for that and most VPN providers have instructions for setting it up on their websites.

Comment: I contacted the ISP and they configured it, now it works. Thanks